# Can't put an URI path of an image to imageview in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, uri

I am trying to make two apps which communicate with each other via content provider. The content Provider is working fine and the data is getting transferred. The problem comes in the image path that I am sending via the content provider.

```
  values.put(StudentsProvider.IMG_URL,selectedImage.toString());
```

This is the data i am storing in the content provider. The selectedImage is the uri object. I am trying to retrieve this string in other app and displaying it in listview.

```
        viewHolder.img1.setImageURI(Uri.parse(img[position]));
```

img[position] contains the string sent by selectedImage.tostring(). The data is being transferred between the two apps but the image in not showing.

```
class ViewHolder

{

    CircleImageView img1;

    ViewHolder(View v)
    {

        img1 = (CircleImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);


    }


}
```

Comment: This is the very first time I have asked a question. Please tell me if I didn't give enough info. or the questions seems to be unclear.

Answer (score 0):

First compress the drawable to bitmap...

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.icon_resource);
```

You can try drawable without compressing also.

Then Use Glide library...

```
GlideApp
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(icon) //
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(myImageView)
    .into(myImageView);
```

More about Glide library..
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific or provide a link so that i can understand better.